# Mule 3.9.0 CE payload problem with transformation

Tags: mule, transformation

I'm writing with a very strange problem I have noticed in my MULE CE 3.9.0 runtime. I even think, it's a bug in the whole stuff.
To the point:
There is a API Manager build with Mule 3.9.0.
Then after making some request via postman, API GW is catching it and first thing is saving the origin payload to some variable. Let's say `stored_payload`

Then I'm making some ASYNC call to log this request (REST request to another microservice). It's whole packed with the `message_enricher`.

In this async call, I need to write down the payload (which is in var: `stored_payload`). It's obviusly `Buffer Input Stream` so I need firstly to convert it to the string.
As we know payload is variable, so I can't use the Mule transformer, but need to write my own in Grovvy.

```
IOUtils.toString({stored_payload}, 'UTF-8')
```

can do the thing.

After that I'm back to call the real business API and here we have my problem.
It's seems that with that Grovvy operation on the `stored_payload` there is NO BODY which is SET and SEND to call the real business API. (payload is empty, but the origin stored_payload remian as BufferInputStream).

I'm attaching needed XMLs:

```
<flow name="logInputRequest">
    <set-variable variableName="params" value="#[new java.util.HashMap();]" doc:name="define FlowVars MAP"/>

 <scripting:component doc:name="Create request params">
                                                <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.lang.String;
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    
def transformedPayload = IOUtils.toString(message.getInvocationProperty('stored_payload'), 'UTF-8')
if(message.getInvocationProperty('as_context') != null){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message.getInvocationProperty('as_context'));
        if(obj != null && obj.getJSONObject("accessTokenInfo") != null){
            JSONObject accessTokenInfo = obj.getJSONObject("accessTokenInfo");
            flowVars.params.put("ownerCif",obj.getString("cif"));
            flowVars.params.put("userNik", accessTokenInfo.getInt("user"));
            flowVars.params.put("ownerNik", obj.getString("owner"));
            flowVars.params.put("userCif", accessTokenInfo.getInt("userId"));
        }
    }
flowVars.params.put("isResponse",false);
flowVars.params.put("parentSpanId", message.getInvocationProperty("x-b3-parentspanid"));
    flowVars.params.put("httpStatus", null);
    flowVars.params.put("description", "Request invoked successfully");
    flowVars.params.put("hostName", message.getInvocationProperty('remote_address') + ' (Mule)');
 
flowVars.params.put("apiUri", flowVars.endpoint);
flowVars.params.put("payload", "URI: "+ message.getInvocationProperty('incoming_properties')['http.request.uri'] + 
    " PARAMS: " + message.getInvocationProperty('query_params').toString() + 
    " PAYLOAD: "+ transformedPayload);
    flowVars.params.put("correlationId", message.getInvocationProperty('requestId'));

<flow-ref name="logCreateParamshttpRequest" doc:name="Log Platform Create REF"/>

</flow>
```

And the flow-ref DEF:

```
<flow name="logCreateParamshttpRequest">
<flow-ref name="encodeHmacAndAddToSession" doc:name="encodeHmac"/>
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.params]" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Body"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
<http:request config-ref="openapi-admin" path="/platform/log/create" method="POST" doc:name="Log Platform Create">
<http:request-builder>
                    <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="Bearer #[flowVars.keycloak]"/>
                    <http:header headerName="Hmac" value="#[sessionVars.hmac]"/>
                </http:request-builder>
            </http:request>
            <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
                <logger message="################# ERROR - While creating request for Admin Log. Process will continue as it's not necessary to be valid in whole flow. Error message: #[flowVars.errorMessage or org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(exception.?getCauseException().?getMessage())]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

And the very first flow (which is starting everything) with the async.

```
[....... some beggining code.....]
<logger message="BEFORE 1 REQUEST #[flowVars.stored_payload] #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<async doc:name="Async">
<enricher target="#[flowVars.logInput]" doc:name="Log input request">
<flow-ref name="logInputRequest" doc:name="LOG INPUT REQUEST"/>
</enricher> 
</async>
<logger message="AFTER 1 REQUEST #[flowVars.stored_payload] #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Is there any chance, that setting above variable changes the whole payload and that's why it isn't send to the real businness API?
Any help would be much appereciated.

Comment: How do you write the string in the async? Please share the XML of the Async and its content.

Comment: Also, where did you put the Groovy, inside or before the Async? What is the payload used for in the rest of the flow?

Comment: @aled I did shared the XML. Groovy is inside the Async. Payload is a json, but when it started to be executing, it's obviusly BufferInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it is not possible to be sure, but the most likely cause is that the stream is consumed by a different thread in the rest of the flow. If the payload is a reference to the stream, if it is read completely by a different thread (async scope runs in its own thread) then any references to it will find it empty.

As an alternative if you convert the stream to a string before the async it will be available inside and outside the async scope, though if it is too big it can cause memory issues because strings must be present completely in memory, unlike streams.

Comment: I though so liek you did, but when I do not transform the 'stored_payload' to String, it's normal, it's ok. The body is send. The only difference is: In case it's ok, I don't transform the payload (but I need to), with case with error: I did it like I've written.

Comment: If it works when not transforming to String why do you need to do it? The HTTP Requester, and probably most Mule operations, understand streams and don´t need the transformation.

Comment: Yeah, it's true, but one bussiness case of my flow is to send payload as plain text and read it from database. When I do not transform it from Stream, i'm getting sth like "BuffferInputStream@435sda" which is no acceptable.

Comment: It looks like you need to serialize (convert to string in this case) the stream before the async.Have you tried just adding an object to string transformer just before?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to say before the async.

Comment: Did you try the transformer just before the Async?

Comment: Yes I did, but with no success.